# Excel - Struggling with complex Index/Match/Match lookup

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I've got a table with 9 columns and about 6000 rows.  Each row has a price as the last column.  Some of those prices are 0.00 when they should be a value.

In another worksheet I have the "original" table with about 3700 rows.  The prices I need are in those rows.  However, the original table has the prices horizontally within the rows, each next to a cell with specific range of gals.  Basically the table I have has unique rows for every location/gal range/price combo, the original has all gal range/prices sequentially in single location rows

For example, a row in the original table looks like this:

```
... / 1-2000 / 2.8383 / 2001-4000 / 2.5382 / ...
```

Where as in my new table they look like this:

```
... / 1-2000 / 2.8383
... / 20001-4000 / 2.5382
etc
```

Everything is the same in my new table and the original table EXCEPT those gal ranges and prices.

What I'm trying to do is use an array multiple criteria Index/Match (based on 3 cells in both my new table and the original) to lookup the row, find the value that matches the range of gals, and then take the price to the right of that gal range cell.

Here is a row I'm trying to get the value for in my new table:
[image: row in new table]

Here is the row with the value I need in the original table:
[image: row with value in original table]

Here's a closer look at the formula I've constructed:

```
INDEX(old!$A$2:$Q$3755,MATCH(1,(A29=old!$A$2:$A$3755)*(F29=old!$F$2:$F$3755)*(G29=old!$G$2:$G3755),1),MATCH(H29,old!$J$2:$Q$3755,1)+1)
```

The first standard Index/Match part works great... I Index the table and Match to find the row.  If I just enter a number for the Col (e.g., 1, 2, 3) it'll return the value from the corresponding cell PERFECTLY.  However, I can't seem to make the Col match part work... I continuously get REF and N/A errors.

Is there some trick to doing a two way search?  It seems like it should be a simple thing to just find that value in the row and take the next cell after if...?

One catch here is that the gal range value I'm looking for is NOT unique... there are at least 20 other references that have the same range (e.g., "1-2000").  Is there a way to limit the col match to just the row I find with the row match?

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: You use a lot of words, but it's still not clear what your data looks like. The only difference I can see from your sample are three dots in the middle instead of the end. It would greatly help to see a real data sample in a real Excel grid. Screenshot or workbook on an ad-free service like DropBox or OneDrive will work. A simplified example rather than your whole workbook. Edit the question. then post a comment. Do not post clarification in comments.

Comment: Sorry, I had thought my explanation was pretty thorough. 
 Unfortunately sharing the raw data isn't feasible since it's sensitive.  Basically I need some insight on why a match for a col number would fail in the Index Match formula provided above.

Comment: In an Index(match,match) combo, the second match identifies the column and typically looks in one row only, i.e. the title row, where the title of the column is found and matched. You are giving it the whole table. is that intended?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, Stack modified those quick comparison samples... the second sample should have had the gal ranges/prices on different lines (rather than the same line, as they are in the original).  To your second comment, okay, well, col match to just the first row (headers) won't work since the value I'm looking for could be in any of 5 different columns per row (e.g., the gal range could be "1500-3000", and that could be in col 7, col 9, col 11, etc).  I need to look for the gal range value in the row that Index/Match returns and then get the value in the cell next to it if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with Index/Match, but you have to keep your cool.

My Screenshot for reference

[image]

The formula in cell F7 is

```
=INDEX(
INDEX(A2:A3,MATCH(B7&C7&D7,INDEX(A2:A3&C2:C3&F2:F3,0),0))
  :INDEX(L2:L3,MATCH(B7&C7&D7,INDEX(A2:A3&C2:C3&F2:F3,0),0)),
MATCH(E7,
     INDEX(A2:A3,MATCH(B7&C7&D7,INDEX(A2:A3&C2:C3&F2:F3,0),0))
     :INDEX(L2:L3,MATCH(B7&C7&D7,INDEX(A2:A3&C2:C3&F2:F3,0),0)),0)
+1)
```

To explain: First we build an Index on column A finding the row with a concatenation of the three values. That is combined with the union operator `:` with an Index on column L, using the same Match.

This Index will return one row of data, from column A to L. It is then used as the range argument for another Index/Match, where inside that row of data Match looks for the "g value" and adds 1 to move one to the right of the found cell.

Note that you don't want whole columns in this formula, since it will be very slow to calculate.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  That solution seems a tad... complicated, and kind of heavy on the processing side?  I mean, it seems like it should be easier to find the value I'm looking for since I can definitively use a multiple criteria match function to tell me the exact row the value is in...?  Am I missing something?

Comment: finding the row number is only one part of the problem. Since you want to search in that found row, you need the whole range, not just the row number. There is definitely duplication of the Index/Match, but since Excel worksheet formulas don't have re-usable variables, there is no way around that.

Comment: btw, the other problem with this approach is that I don't know which column the price value I need is in... you have L2:L3 references in the formula for a specific price column.  However, using your example the the price I need could be in H, J, or L... it depends on where the match is found for the G value(E7).  The underlying issue here is really that I don't know which column will potentially have that G value, and where to look for price.  I have to detect it...

Comment: No, column L is just the end of the range. The beginning is Index(A...):Index(L ...)

Comment: Gotcha.  Couldnt get sumproduct to work properly, so I just decided to go back and muscle the original indirect solution.  Got it to work and no +1 indexing, seems perfect!  Nice job, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

One way to tackle this case is to use `#powerquery`.

Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use **Power Query** on your version of Excel. It is availeble in **Excel 2010 Professional Plus and later versions**. My demonstration is using **Excel 2016**.

The steps are:

1. Load/Add your old data to the Power Query Editor. My sample data only has one row but it is same for thousands of rows;

[image: Sample Data]

2. Use **Merge Columns** function under `Transform` tab to merge the first **7** columns with a delimiter say semicolon `;`;
3. Repeat **Merge Columns** for each pair of `GALLONS` and `TOTAL PRICES` with the same delimiter `;`. If you have done it correctly you should have something like the following:

[image: Merged]

4. Use **Unpivot Columns** function under `Transform` tab to unpivot all the merged columns for `GALLONS;TOTAL PRICE`, then remove the `Attribute` column;

[image: Unpivoted]

5. Use **Split Column** function under the `Transform` tab to split each column by delimiter `;`. If you have done it correctly you should have something like the following:

[image: Splited]

6. **Make a duplicate column** of the `GALLONS` range column (which is the second last column in the above screen-shot), and then split the original `GALLONS` range column by delimiter `-`. Then you should have:

[image: Splited2]

7. **Rename** the column headers as desired;

[image: Renamed]

8. **Close & Load** the new table to a new worksheet (by default) or you can change the default setting and create a connection for the new table and load it to a desired location in your workbook.

[image: Output]

The second table is the output table and you can do **INDEX+MATCH** from this new table which should be much easier than from the old table. If the data are identical but just in different structure then you may just use the output table without worrying about looking up missing prices.

I have added a test line to my source table and here is the **Refreshed** output with a click of button:

[image: Output2]

Here are the power query M codes behind the scene for reference only. All steps are performed using built-in functions of the editor which is quite straight forward.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"IATA", Int64.Type}, {"ST", type text}, {"FUELER", type text}, {"UPDATED", type datetime}, {"RESTRICTIONS", type text}, {"BASEF UEL", type text}, {"NOTES", type any}, {"GALLONS1", type text}, {"TOTAL PRICES1", type text}, {"GALLONS2", type text}, {"TOTAL PRICES2", type text}, {"GALLONS3", type text}, {"TOTAL PRICES3", type text}, {"GALLONS4", type text}, {"TOTAL PRICES4", type text}, {"GALLONS5", type text}, {"TOTAL PRICES5", type text}}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"IATA", type text}, {"UPDATED", type text}, {"NOTES", type text}}, "en-AU"),{"IATA", "ST", "FUELER", "UPDATED", "RESTRICTIONS", "BASEF UEL", "NOTES"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Merged Columns1" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns",{"GALLONS1", "TOTAL PRICES1"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.1"),
    #"Merged Columns2" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns1",{"GALLONS2", "TOTAL PRICES2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.2"),
    #"Merged Columns3" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns2",{"GALLONS3", "TOTAL PRICES3"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.3"),
    #"Merged Columns4" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns3",{"GALLONS4", "TOTAL PRICES4"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.4"),
    #"Merged Columns5" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns4",{"GALLONS5", "TOTAL PRICES5"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.5"),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Merged Columns5", {"Merged"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Merged", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Merged.1", "Merged.2", "Merged.3", "Merged.4", "Merged.5", "Merged.6", "Merged.7"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Merged.1", Int64.Type}, {"Merged.2", type text}, {"Merged.3", type text}, {"Merged.4", type datetime}, {"Merged.5", type text}, {"Merged.6", type text}, {"Merged.7", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Value.1", "Value.2"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Value.1", type text}, {"Value.2", type text}}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type2", "Value.1", "Value.1 - Copy"),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{"Merged.1", "Merged.2", "Merged.3", "Merged.4", "Merged.5", "Merged.6", "Merged.7", "Value.1 - Copy", "Value.1", "Value.2"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter2" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Value.1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Value.1.1", "Value.1.2"}),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter2",{{"Value.1.1", Int64.Type}, {"Value.1.2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type3",{{"Merged.1", "IATA"}, {"Merged.2", "ST"}, {"Merged.3", "FUELER"}, {"Merged.4", "UPDATED"}, {"Merged.5", "RESTRICTIONS"}, {"Merged.6", "BASEF UEL"}, {"Merged.7", "NOTES"}, {"Value.1 - Copy", "GALLONS"}, {"Value.1.1", "Min Fuel"}, {"Value.1.2", "Max Fuel"}, {"Value.2", "TOTAL PRICE"}}),
    #"Changed Type4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"UPDATED", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, not using Index/Match at all, but Sumproduct instead. in F7:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$L$3,($A$2:$A$3=B7)*($C$2:$C$3=C7)*($F$2:$F$3=D7)*($A$2:$K$3=E7))
```

Note that the offset of one column is achieved with the first range from B to L and the last range from A to K.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, much easier.  However, when I tailor it for my worksheets I get a #VALUE result. :(  The formula I'm using is as follows... for reference, the "top" table in your sample is my "old" worksheet, the bottom references are the new worksheet (where I have my ref values) =SUMPRODUCT(old!$B$2:$Q$3755,(old!$A$2:$A$3755=A29)*(old!$C$2:$C$3755=C29)*(old!$F$2:$F$3755=F29)*(old!$J$2:$P$3755=H29))

Comment: Look at the references. The first one is B to Q, so if you want to offset by one column to the right for the value, the last reference needs to be C to R. Or should the first one be A to P and the last one B to Q??

Comment: Scratch that, I tweaked it to facilitate the offset, but for some reason I just get 0?  =SUMPRODUCT(old!$B$2:$Q$3755,(old!$A$2:$A$3755=A29)*(old!$C$2:$C$3755=C29)*(old!$F$2:$F$3755=F29)*(old!$A$2:$P$3755=H29))

Comment: now you're returning one cell to the left of the found cell.

Comment: I think you need to swap the first and last ranges  =SUMPRODUCT(old!$A$2:$P$3755,(old!$A$2:$A$3755=A29)*(old!$C$2:$C$3755=C29)*(old!$F$2:$F$3755=F29)*(old!$B$2:$Q$3755=H29))

Comment: HOLY #%$!  It worked!  I have to test it across the different cells to make sure it gets the proper values (couple spot samples should do), but DAMN... nice work. :)

Comment: Okay, so it seems to work.  The only issue is that for some reason all of the prices are indexed +1.  What I mean by that is that for any given row there are 2-4 prices, and in my new table I have 2-4 rows for each single row in the original.  When I apply that formula I get the prices, but they are all for the "previous" gallon band.  E.g., Row 77 has 3.53, but that price is the previous band.  Basically it's taking the price from the "left of" where it finds the gallon match, but it should be taking it from the right?

Comment: E.g., in your example, p1 is showing up for g2, when I actually need p2.  BTW, thanks for all this help, youre a lifesaver!